# Managing FreeBSD Jails programmatically

Tags: c, interop, freebsd, jail

Is it possible to manage the FreeBSD jails programmatically (create jails, perform snapshots, etc)? I know there is a `libjail`, but I couldn't find any examples.

Comment: Just in case you can use this image https://fabrik.red using zfs+jails as a base to start testing creating/cloning etc

Answer (score 1):

On a FreeBSD system enter `apropos jail` to get all available manpages for jail.

You are looking for the manpages in section 2 and section 3.

start with `man 2 jail`

Answer (score 1):

There are several available in the ports tree. Like [ezjail](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/ezjail/) or [qjail](http://qjail.sourceforge.net/).

For exemples on doing that from a C(++) program, look at the [jail(3)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jail&sektion=3) manual page.

Comment: The both of them are wrappers for the `jail` user space command. What I need are examples in C/C++ language.